# React child prop update not causing action in parent

Tags: reactjs, components, onclicklistener

I know I'm making a silly mistake here but comb my code as I might I can't figure out why its not working. Let me start at the beginning

I'm trying to have an onClick listener in a child component that changes the prop of the child. The change in the child prop should cause a change in state of the parent (by use of a click handler function), but for some reason its not. I can confirm that the prop of the child is changing and I can confirm that the changeState function of the parent isn't being fired. Can anybody tell me why? Here's the code:

```
class Table extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.ajaxCall = this.ajaxCall.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      query : 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent',
      users : undefined
    }
    this.changeQueryState = this.changeQueryState.bind(this)
  }


  changeQueryState(query){

    if (query != this.state.query){
      this.setState({
        query :   query
      })
    }
  }

  render(){
      if (this.state.users){
    return (
      <table className='table table-bordered table-striped'>
        <TableToolbar onClick={this.changeQueryState}/>
        <Users rows={this.state.users}/>
      </table>
    )
  }      else{
        return null
      }
  }
}




class TableToolbar extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this)
  }

  onClickHandler(clicked){
    if (clicked.target.id === "30"){
        this.props.onClick = 
  'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent'
        } else if (clicked.target.id == "alltime"){
       this.props.onClick = 
 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime'
      }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <thead>
          <tr className="row m-0">
            <th className="col-1">#</th>
            <th className="col-6">Camper Name</th>
            <th className="col-3"><p className="clickable" id="30" 
onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Points In Past 30 Days</p></th>
            <th className="col-2"><p className="clickable" 
id="alltime" onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Points Alltime</p></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    )
  }
}
```

changeQueryState in the Table class is what's not working. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the parent function:

`this.props.onClick('<url>')` instead of `this.props.onClick = '<url>'`

Also `this.state.users` is empty so the Table will never render.

Comment: nice, knew I was missing something easy. Also I have this.state.users and a whole other component I just didn't show it cause it doesn't pertain to the problem I was having. Thanks for answering!

Comment: I have another question I've been struggling with, maybe you can help me. When the state I want another ajax call to be made so as to update the Users on the table. I currently make the ajax call in componentDidMount but that only happens once. What would be the best way to impliment an ajax call when the state of query changes?